# Disabling Wysyig profile for a particular content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg, content-type

I am using [CKeditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) with [wysiwyg](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) profile . I want to disable this [wysiwyg](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) profile for a particular content type. cant find a better way. please help me out with any module if its there or any configuration setting if its possible

Answer (score 1):

1) While configuring the field, on **Text Processing** use **Plain text** instead of filtered text.

2) If this doesn't work use the [better_formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module to restrict access to wysiwyg editor profiles.